# Jest unit testing

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am using Jest for writing coded unit test for my project, In one of the code the lambda function is inside the try and catch block like

```
   try {
    "use strict";
    const somevalue = require("./somefile")

    export.somefunction = ((event,context,()=>{

    return something

    }).catch((error)=>{

      return error
    }

    }
    catch(exception){
    console.log(exception)
    }
```

I want to understand two things
a) What purpose does writing lambda function inside the try/catch block do, 
   considering the lambda exception is handled
b) Second how write the jest coded unit test case for try/catch block

Comment: Did you try to ask a person who wrote it? It makes no sense. Suppressing an error will result in empty export from this module and thus in an error in parent module which expects to import a function from this module.

Comment: I am new to this project and I have no clue who has written this code, however any thoughts on second point or is it better to remove the try/catch block

Comment: Remove outer try..catch with no doubt. And I'm not sure about `.catch((error)=>{` inside because the syntax is wrong.

Comment: thanks @estus for the suggestion, i have removed the outer try/catch block